# Cannot open file python37_d.lib in configuring OpenCV and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I was following a tutorial to configure OpenCV and Visual Studio using CMake for C++.
When I built the  "All Build" under CMakeTargets in debug mode, I am getting an error

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'python37_d.lib'
```

I was not able to find any solution on the internet/google.

Answer (score -1):

there is no such thing as a `python37_d.lib` shipped with python

(you can only build opencv python bindings in RELEASE mode)

(( IF you REALLY want this, it needs building your *python* from src, in DEBUG mode ))

Comment: So is it fine if I don't install it and ignore the error ?

Comment: Interesting, I do have it both in 32bit as well as 64bit Python 3.7.5. Definitely didn't build my own, just installed using standard distribution packages for WIndows. There are even debug versions of the command line interpreters there too.